# How can I indicate that n and k are natural numbers in ∀n[(∀k < n P(k)) → P(n)].

Tags: predicate-logic

$∀\, x \, \{x\in\mathbb N\rightarrow P(x)\}$ can be abbreviated to $∀ \hspace{.1cm} x∈ℕ[P(x)].$
But, I am not sure how I can indicate "concisely" that n and k are natural numbers in ∀n[(∀k < n P(k)) → P(n)], which is strong induction.

To do it verbosely, I could write $∀n∈N[∀k∈N(k<n \rightarrow P(k)) → P(n)]$, but it looks ugly and is difficult to read.

Comment: 3 is actually meant to be a placeholder for an arbitrary natural number.

Comment: $$P(1)\land P(2)\land P(3)$$

Comment: What's wrong with $\forall n[(\forall k<n\ P(k))\implies P(n)]$, which you have in your question?

Comment: ∀n[(∀k<n P(k))⟹P(n)] itself doesn't indicate that n and k are natural numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually write this as

$$\forall n\in\Bbb N,(\forall k\in\{1\dots n-1\},P(k)\implies P(n))$$

where $\{1\dots n-1\}$ is the set of integers between $1$ and $n-1$ inclusive. [Example.](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/nnsinds.html) If you have a notation for $\Bbb N\cap[1,n)$ instead of $\Bbb N\cap[1,n-1]$ that's even better (but I think would not be as universally recognized as $\{1\dots n-1\}$).

Comment: It's not completely satisfactory, but you made realize that I better mention that k is a natural number in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would write

$$\forall \,x \in\mathbb N\left[x\leq 3\rightarrow P(x)\right]
$$

Not much of an improvement,
but hey.

Comment: I was trying to avoid it because it was verbose.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
$$\forall x\in\mathbb N\cap[0,3][P(x)]$$
where $[0,3]$ means the closed interval from $0$ to $3$.

Or:
$$\forall x\in 4[P(x)]$$
since $4=\{0,1,2,3\}$ in set theory.

EDIT: This is in response to the question before the edit

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion with 3. It was replaced with k.